# SWUpdate API with Qt

Tags: linux, qt, embedded, swupdate

I'm trying to update my application using SWUpdate tool for my embedded board.
I already created my .swu pack, anche with ssh command line, it works fine.
I need to launch the update from my Qt application.
How can I do?

Maybe I can launch QProcess::execute("swupdate -i /run/media/AppUpdate.swu"), but it still not working.

How can I link with Qt the SWUpdate API installed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You did not state which Qt version you are using. The more recent ones deprecated the QProcess::execute call as you are using it (program name and arguments in one string).

Try this:

```
QProcess* proc = new QProcess;
proc->setProgram("swupdate");
proc->setArguments(QStringList({"-i", "path/to/your/update.swu"});
proc->start();
if (!proc->waitForStarted()) 
    qCritical() << "failed to start swupdate: " << proc->errorString();
/*optional: block/wait for swupdate to finish*/
proc->waitForFinished(-1);
```

I recommend to also implement and connect the **readyRead** signal and save/log swupdate's output in case something goes wrong during the update.

Comment: I think i found the solution.
I need to append after command the '&' symbol.
In the string:

QProcess* proc = new QProcess;
proc->setProgram("swupdate");
proc->setArguments(QStringList({"-i", "path/to/your/update.swu &"});    <-----
proc->start();
if (!proc->waitForStarted()) 
    qCritical() << "failed to start swupdate: " << proc->errorString();
/*optional: block/wait for swupdate to finish*/
proc->waitForFinished(-1);